# What are universal abstract $\sigma$-algebras on $\sigma$-frames?

Tags: ct.category-theory, measure-theory, lattice-theory

*Originally asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561005/what-are-universal-abstract-sigma-algebras-on-sigma-frames).*

In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3762) paper, the authors make the following definitions:

- An (abstract) $\sigma$-algebra is a boolean algebra with countable joins.
- A $\sigma$-frame is a bounded lattice with countable joins, where the distributive law holds ($-\wedge x$ preserves countable joins)

Respective notions of morphisms are the obvious ones; morphisms preserve all the given structure. On page 7 (above Lemma 3) they claim, that there is a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of $\sigma$-algebras to the category of $\sigma$-frames.

> How does "this" left-adjoint look like explicitely?

Comment: My guess is that you get the universal abstract $\sigma-$algebra by adding formal complements of the elements in your $\sigma-$frame in a similar way to how you construct the Grothendieck group for a commutative monoid or localize a commutative ring. Note that the explicit construction isn't that important, you get the existence of the adjoint by the adjoint functor theorem (the forgetful functor preserves limits).

Comment: I tried to answer your question in the corresponding [MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2823559/123855).

Comment: @TomasJakl Thanks. It'll take some time for me to look trough it. I have literally not dealt with this topic since then.